# Вопрос с селектрами в JQuery

Tags: jquery

Здравствуйте.
Стал разбираться с JQuery. Пишу:

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
$(".right").hover(function()
{
$(".right").animate(
{
    width: '15%'
},
    1500,
    function()
    {
        $(this).html("<p><a href='#'> Оставить отзыв</a> </p> ");
    })
})
```

а потом пытаюсь таким вот образом сделать что-нибудь с "Оставить отзыв":

```
$(".right p a").toggle(
function()
{
  $(".left").animate(
  {
      opacity: '1'        
  },
  1500);
},
function()
{
  $(".left").animate(
  {
      opacity: '0'
  },
  1500);
})
```

но ничего не происходит. как правильно обратиться к этим элементам, подскажите, пожалуйста?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте заменить строки типа *$(".right").animate(* на *$(this).animate(* . И еще раз пересмотреть, правильность выбора элемента.
Кстати, если элементы .right и .right p a добавляются на страницу динамически, к ним не привязываются эти события. Почитайте про метод live().

Comment: да, судя по всему, live() - это то, что мне нужно. спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант вынести отдельно `...$(".right p a").toggle( ...` в функцию `newFunction()` а в `<p><a href='#'> Оставить отзыв</a> </p>` добавить `onclick="newFunction()"`